# Delete empty "lost+found" folder automatically if it's empty

Tags: filesystem, nfs, folder

Every certain amount of time, Ubuntu checks my filesystems and it creates several empty "*lost+found*" folders.

Can I disable this feature? Is there any way that Ubuntu deletes automatically these folders if they are empty?

---

Is there any manner to hide this folder on NFS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever `fsck` goes through the system and tries to recover damaged files, it will put them into the lost+found folder. I guess this is basically a problem with `fsck` creating that folder even if there's nothing to put in. As Ubuntu periodically runs those checks on your partitions, those folders will always be re-created, so deleting it won't work.

If you just want to hide the folder from Nautilus, you can create a '.hidden' file containing 'lost+found' and put it into the lost+found parent's folder.

Eg. for the lost+found folder in '/':

`echo "lost+found" | sudo tee /.hidden`

For the one in you home directory (if any):

`echo "lost+found" > ~/.hidden`

---

I guess alternatively you can remove them after every boot by adding the following to the file '/etc/rc.local':

```
if [ -d /lost+found ]; then
    rmdir /lost+found 2>/dev/null
fi

if [ -d /home/USER/lost+found ]; then
    rmdir /home/USER/lost+found 2>/dev/null
fi
```

This will run `rmdir` on the folders if they exist, which only removes them if they are empty (`2>/dev/null` will discard the "not empty" message from `rmdir`). There probably aren't lots of directories, so I kept it simple. Just make sure 'exit 0' stays on the bottom line.

Downside: this only keeps track of directories created by `fsck` during boot. If it's run at a later time, you'll again see that directory. You then could put above into a periodically executed [cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: Thanks, I knew this but that solution only works for nautilus.

Comment: And how can I hide this folder on NFS?

Comment: See update. Sorry, I have no experience with NFS.

Answer (score 4):

> [Having a] lost+found directory with a large enough size to contain a large number of unlinked files puts less of a burden on e2fsck to create the directory and grow it to the appropriate size.
>
> [fsck will attempt to create lost+found if it doesn't exist], [but in the face of a corrupt filesystem, it can be more risky.](https://serverfault.com/questions/6753/what-happens-if-i-delete-lostfound)
>
> Very old fsck's for other filesystems on other platforms were not able to create /lost+found, nor were they able to grow it. This is the history for the rationale of /lost+found...

It is needed much less often since ext3.  With a journaling filesystem, files shouldn't get "lost" on a crash / power failure.  You might argue it's only kept to avoid fatal surprises for old-timers (and weirdos who disable the journal).  If you don't know what you're missing, maybe it's not a problem.

Still, removing it is like patching e2fsck.  You "can" do it, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This article will give you a proper explanation about lost+found directory :
http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/lostfound.html

Comment: Thanks, I knew this but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

`cd where the lost+found folder is located`
`sudo touch .hidden`
`sudo mcedit .hidden` (Write `lost+found` and save with <kbd>F2</kbd>.)